# Are laptop LCD cables interchangeable?

Tags: laptop, lcd, cable

I do a fair amount of laptop repair for my job. One of our most common issues is people coming in with broken screens; in such cases, it can be hard to figure out if the cable is broken or the screen is broken. LVDS cables I've seen tend to look extremely similar to each other. If they were interchangeable, it would be possible to have a known-good spare cable to try swapping in (like we do for memory). They wouldn't have to give peak performance, just carry some signal, get the screen to display *something*, and not damage anything. Being the proper size doesn't matter, because a test could be done with screen removed.

Is that possible with laptop LCD cables, or do models of laptop tend to have very differing LVDS cables such that it makes no sense to have one or a few KG LVDS cables on hand?

Comment: http://forums.hackaday.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3980 is worth a read. It might come down to more than electrical/physical compatibility by the looks of things.